# How to remove non null assertion in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i am new to programming and i am trying to remove non-null assertion in the code below,

```
const children: someData[] = flatten(
  someData
    .filter(({ children }) => children)
    .map(({ children }) => children!) //remove non null assertion operator
);
const nestedChildren = flatten(
  children
    .filter(({ children }) => children)
    .map(({ children }) => children!) //remove non null assertion operator
);
```

as seen from code above there is non null assertion operator in map method how can i rewrite the code above such that i dont get error "undefined cannot be assigned to type children'

if i remove non null assertion operator i get error like above. could someone help me fix this. thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can try `someData.reduce((list,{children}) => children ? [ ...list, children] : list, [])`. You can also add return type to filter: `:{ children: number }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [custom type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)

```js
const children = [{ children: 42 }, {}]
    .filter((elem): elem is { children: number } => Boolean(elem.children))
    .map(({ children }) => children)
```